# why is it only gridding the label on row 1, column1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I made a simple tkinter app that has a button and a label. I tried to grid the label on row 2, column 2, but it only grid it on row 1, column 1. Please help me. I am new to tkinter.

This is my code:

````
window = Tk()
window.title("hihi")
def qw():
    label.config(text="hi")
button = Button(text = "hi", command = qw).grid(row=0, column=0)
label = Label(text="")
label.grid(row=2, column=2)```
````

Comment: Empty rows take up no space, hence without any widgets(or some `minsize`) in row 0 to 1 or column 0 to 1, your widget will look like being at row 0 and column 0

Comment: In your own words: if you put something into `0,0` and into `2,2` and *there is nothing else in the grid*, why should the result *look different* from the result if you used `1,1` instead of `2,2`? *How* should it look different?

Comment: ok i will fix my code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need define the size of the column and row. If there is no text in the cell, then there is nothing to render, and it takes up no space. So you `column=2` and `row=2` looks like its at `column=1` and `row=1`.

By adding `window.columnconfigure(1, minsize=5)` and `window.rowconfigure(1, minsize=5)` you force that cell to take up space on the window.

The following code will make it looks like "hi" is being printed on (2,2), but you may have to tinker with the sizes to make it look even. (perhaps set a minsize for all rows and columns)

```
import tkinter as tk


def qw():
    label.config(text="hi")


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("hihi")
button = tk.Button(window, text="hi", command=qw, borderwidth=6, relief='raised')
label = tk.Label(window, text="", borderwidth=6, relief='raised')
button.grid(row=0, column=0)
label.grid(row=2, column=2)
window.columnconfigure(1, minsize=5) # Forces the columns at index 1 to have a min size of 5
window.rowconfigure(1, minsize=5) # Forces the rows at index 1 to have a min size of 5
window.mainloop()
```